# A sum of some Legendre symbols is $\equiv 0 \mod p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, legendre-symbol

Let $p \gt 5$ be a prime number.
Then

$$ \sum_{a = 1}^{\frac{p - 1}{2}} \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) a ^2 \equiv 0 \mod p ?$$

(Where $\left( \frac{a}{p} \right)$ is the Legendre symbol mod. p.)

I could show that
$$ \sum_{a = 1}^{p - 1} \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) a ^2 =  (1 - (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}})\sum_{a = 1}^{\frac{p - 1}{2}} \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) a ^2, $$
and
$$ \sum_{a = 1}^{p - 1} \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) a ^2 \equiv 0 \mod p .$$

So if $p \not\equiv 1 \mod 4$, then ok.

But what about the case $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$?

Comment: You have a sign error, the factor should be $1 + (-1)^{(p-1)/2}$. That gets you the $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ case. As for the $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ case, computing the sum for $p = 7, 11, 19$ shows that for none of these it's a multiple of $p$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much!
It seems that this proof works for $p = 5$, but of course this is false.

Comment: Yes, we have $$\sum_{a = 1}^{5-1} \biggl(\frac{a}{5}\biggr)a^2 = 1 - 4 - 9 + 16 = 4 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{5}\,.$$ The proof that $$\sum_{a = 1}^{p-1} \biggl(\frac{a}{p}\biggr)a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$ requires $p > 5$. (Depending on how you argue, it may also work for $p = 3$ without modifications.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much, I've understood.